# How do I read the value of a checkbox in a word (*.doc) file in VB.net using a Range object?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

How do I read the value of a checkbox in a word (*.doc) file in VB.net using a range object?

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim app As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Document
doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\myDoc.doc")
dim chkBox as Bookmark
chkBox = doc.Bookmarks("MyCheckbox")
Dim rng as Range
rng = chkBox.Range
```

where "MyCheckbox" is the bookmark of the checkbox in the word document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you're not reading the value of the checkbox using the name of the checkbox itself?

If the range defined by your bookmark contains a checkbox, then, depending upon how the checkbox is inserted, it will be found in either the `InlineShapes` collection (if checkbox inserted inline with the text) or the `Shapes` collection (if inserted as a floating object.)

You would then need to iterate through the collection of Shapes or InlineShapes looking for the checkbox in question.

*Iterating through controls in InlineShapes collection*

```
Dim ctl As InlineShape
For Each ctl In rng.InlineShapes
    If ctl.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
        If ctl.OLEFormat.ClassType Like "Forms.CheckBox*" Then
            'current version of ctl is a checkbox, do what you will with it.

        End If
    End If
Next ctl
...
```

This ought to get you closer, but if the name of the checkbox is predictable, it is better to address it directly by name.